# ExtJS: Implementing a parent reference in model

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs6

Currently on 6.0.1. Making a transition from 4.1.
The issue is we want to be able to retain the ability to reference the parent model via the field "parent". The reason for doing this involves a lot of code written to this point.
From the previous build we had under the "Ext.data.association.HasMany" and "Ext.data.association.HasMany" overridden the "read" function with the ExtJS default with adding in the "parent" field after getting the new Store of records from the reader and applying it each to below
I have attempted to add this in the ExtJS6 project by using this [link](http://moduscreate.com/associations-in-ext-js-5/). Using this, I have done like in the example given for ManyToOne and set a parent field to each left record on iteration, but this yields no change.

1. Could I use the existing overrides? I know I saw something about using legacy associations so I would hope I can tie back into that if possible.
2. If not, how should I go about adding in this parent reference?